# Escaping asterisk in shell script when Java program is invoked

Tags: shell, escaping, wildcard, arguments

I've a simple java program which just prints the arguments passed

```
public class CmdArgsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(String arg : args){
            System.out.println(arg);    
        }
    }
}
```

I'm invoking this java program from a shell script `setupTest.sh` like this
`java CmdArgsTest $*`

When I invoke `setupTest.sh` with the those arguments `*` gets replaced with all the file names in the directory.

```
setupTest.sh -tt oracle -tn test_ora -sqlQuery "select * from myTable"
```

Even I escape `*` with `\` but the argument is passed is `\*` and not `*` alone. I have also tried putting `*` in quotes but that didn't help.

I cannot run the script as `java CmdArgsTest "$*"` as then all the command is passed a one big string.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank,
Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

try escaping the dollar (`$`) sign

```
java CmdArgsTest "\$*"
```

or using single quotes

```
java CmdArgsTest '$*'
```

same goes for the other invokation:

```
setupTest.sh -tt oracle -tn test_ora -sqlQuery 'select * from myTable'
```